# How do I link to a page in a different or root folder on a Bitbucket wiki?

Tags: bitbucket, wiki

I have this page:

https://bitbucket.org/ekolis/freee/wiki/Screens/MainMenu

I want the word "mod" to link to the Modding page on the wiki, so I linked it to "Modding" - however this links it to Screens/Modding, which doesn't exist! I tried linking to ../Modding and /Modding but neither of those works; they both link to nonexistent pages under the src folder. How do I link to a page that's in the root folder or another folder entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, "../Modding" is the correct link; it's only a bug in Bitbucket's preview feature that made it link to the wrong page!